# 422 Unprocessable Entity error after AJAX POST request in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

On my website, users can reply to blog posts.

It's a bit annoying for the page to refresh when replying, so I decided to try ajax. However, I'm getting an error.

**Form/markup:**

```
<form data-value="{{$status->id}}" class="replyForm" role="form" action="{{ route('status.reply', ['statusId' => $status->id]) }}" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="reply-{{$status->id}}" class="form-control"  placeholder="Reply to this status"></textarea>
    @if ($errors->has("reply-{$status->id}"))
        <span class="help-block">
            {{ $errors->first("reply-{$status->id}") }}
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Reply">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" >
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function postReply(Request $request, $statusId) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        "reply-{$statusId}" => 'required|max:1000|alpha_dash',
      ], [
        'required' => 'The reply body is required.'
    ]);

    $status = Status::notReply()->find($statusId);

    if (!$status) {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    if (!Auth::user()->isFollowing($status->user) && Auth::user()->id !== $status->user->id){
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    $reply = Status::create([
        'body' => $request->input("reply-{$statusId}"),
    ])->user()->associate(Auth::user());

    $status->replies()->save($reply);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('/status/{statusId}/reply', [
    'uses' => '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\StatusController@postReply',
    'as' => 'status.reply', 
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

Now this all works just fine. However, when I try to convert it into an Ajax request:

```
$( ".replyForm" ).submit(function( e ) {

e.preventDefault();

var $token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
var dataString = $(this).serialize();
var $replyValue = $(this).attr('data-value');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: host + '/status/' + $replyValue + '/reply',
    data: {replyValue: $replyValue, _token:$token},
    success: function(res) {

    }
 });
});
```

I get the following error:

> POST XHR http://localhost/status/41/reply [HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable
>   Entity 184ms]

41 being the ID of the status being replied to.

What's causing this?

Comment: validation exception, validation failed

Comment: The reply I'm testing with is just "test". Not sure why it wouldn't pass validation.

Comment: check the request and see if the input you are actually validating against is there, or catch the exception to get the validator errors from it

Comment: newb question but how would I do that?

Comment: sorry about that, you could throw a `dd($request->all());` at the top of that controller method to see the inputs the request has. You can use the tools your browser has to inspect the ajax request and see the response if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the validation, it seems that you are expecting `reply-41` as the input field.

```
"reply-{$statusId}" => 'required|max:1000|alpha_dash',
```

But, from the ajax request you are making, it seems that you are passing the data in `replyValue`

```
data: {replyValue: $replyValue, _token:$token},
```

Thus, the validation rule is failing, because `reply-41` is required.

You can update the server side to expect `replyValue` instead of `reply-{$statusId}` to solve it:

```
"replyValue" => 'required|max:1000|alpha_dash',
// ...
'body' => $request->input("replyValue"),
```